# Spring Boot - JPA - Postgres ERROR: cross-database references are not implemented:

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jpa, multiple-schema

I am using Spring Boot, JPA and Postgres and I have one database with multiple schemas. 
I implement a web service using JPA and I receive this error:

***o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: cross-database references are not implemented: "kaloudia_db_v2.enumeration.unit"***

Do you know any way to overcome this error?

My class is

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "unit", schema = "enumeration", catalog = kaloudia_db_v2")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Unit.findAll", query = "SELECT u FROM Unit u"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Unit.findById", query = "SELECT u FROM Unit u WHERE u.id = :id"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Unit.findByNameEn", query = "SELECT u FROM Unit u WHERE u.nameEn = :nameEn"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Unit.findByNameEl", query = "SELECT u FROM Unit u WHERE u.nameEl = :nameEl")})
public class Unit implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
```

and call of JPA function is:

```
public Object getAllUnits() {
    List<Unit> units = unitRepository.findAll();
    return units;
}
```

Comment: Please write application.properties file.

Comment: Postgres does not support catalogs (=database) as port of an identifier. You should remove the `catalog=...` attribute from the annotation.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name
If I remove the catalogo=... , I receive this error

***ERROR: relation "enumeration.unit" does not exist***

Comment: @jackk
You are right my friend!! 
I forgot to change this property:
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/kaloudia_db_v2

It works now!!

Thank you and I am sorry.

Comment: @psmaster you are welcome .  +1 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jack said, I saw the application properties file and I found out that I forgot to change **spring.datasource.url** property!!

I am sorry for my question!
It works fine now!